# Can Emacs (ESS) evaluate R code chunks within .rmd files and embed the outputs within the same file like R Studio?

Tags: ess, r

Recently tried to start using (Doom) Emacs for writing R code via ESS mode. I was wondering if it's possible to embed the outputs of evaluated code chunks of R Markdown files like in R Studio

Example:
[image]

I'm aware I can kinda use Org mode as a "drop-in" replacement for Rmarkdown, but I'm currently required to use the latter file type.